# tinyDTLS server key configuration

Tags: security, contiki, dtls

I am using a tinyDTLS in my contiki code ..

http://tinydtls.sourceforge.net/

I am currently able to configure client and server and run with the
example keys.

Now I need to configure my client to connect to three servers, if all
server keys are same then I am able to connect.

tinyDTLS source says, we need to use this to get configure the keys

```
  int get_key(struct dtls_context_t *ctx,
        const session_t *session,
        const unsigned char *id, size_t id_len,
        const dtls_key_t **result) {

   static const dtls_key_t psk = {
      .type = DTLS_KEY_PSK,
      .key.psk.id = (unsigned char *)"Client_identity",
      .key.psk.id_length = 15,
      .key.psk.key = (unsigned char *)"secretPSK",
      .key.psk.key_length = 9
     };
```

*result = &psk;
  return 0;
}

At client side how to read "PSK_Identity_hint" sent by server during
key exchange .
and server side how to read PSK_identity ..

if I can read this PSK_Identity_hint, I can select a appropriate key
and  send a PSK_ identity ..

pls help to understand how to configure the keys